# Using CMake to find dependencies in an application-specific subfolder

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, boost, cmake

In spite of many years of coding large-scale C++ applications, I do not understand how find_package is supposed to work in a medium-size CMake project, ASSUMING that I want to build the source to dependent packages myself and not simply rely on large systems like opencv, pcl or boost being installed somewhere in a system folder. I can't can't believe that I'm the only person in the world who has shipped multiple OpenCV and other open-source apps, has worked with meta-build systems like NAnt and SCons on major game projects, yet can't understand the most basic things about how CMake works or find a tutorial answering these questions.

In the past, I have essentially hacked around not understaning find_package by setting all the foo_DIR values by hand as CMake complains until I get a working folder.

I would like to run through a simple example which I'm working on right now, and dearly hope someone can explain what I'm doing so wrong.

Firstly, some assumptions: 
I want to build everything for both MacOS and Windows, ideally via CMakeGUI. MacOS should build XCodeProjects and Windows should build Visual Studio Solutions.

Where there are dependencies, I want to compile them myself, so I have debug symbols and can modify the dependency source (or at least debug into it.) 
No installation of pre-built binaries into system folders, i.e. no use of sudo port install opencv/pcl, etc on mac. 
I have multiple projects, and prefer to keep a project and its dependencies in a single folder. 
For the purposes of a concrete example, suppose I am building this project, although it's an arbitrary choice to illustrate the process and confusion I suffer:

https://github.com/krips89/opendetection

This lists dependencies, which I have intentionally reordered here so that I can take them in order, as follows:

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost 1.40 COMPONENTS program_options REQUIRED )
find_package(PCL REQUIRED)
find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
```

I would like to have all of these dependencies downloaded and configured in a single path (let's say c:\src on Windows, and ~\src on Mac for simplicity), NOT in a system path. Assume that the actual folder is a sub-folder for this project, and no a sub-folder for all projects. This should also allow for side-by-side installation of multiple projects on the same computer.

Taking this one step at a time:

(1) I clone openCV from https://github.com/opencv/opencv, sync to tag 3.1, configure into the folder opencv_build folder, build and install into opencv_install. I've done this so many times it's pretty straightforward. 
(2) As above, but for eigen (although building for eigen doesn't actually do anything s it's a template library. I install to a folder eigen_install

Taking directory shows a series of folders for downloaded dependencies. I have assumed a convention where ,  and  are source repos, and their following _build folders are the "WHere to build the binaries" folders in CMakeGui.

```
$ ls
boost_1_40_0    opencv  opendetection_build
eigen   opencv-build    opendetection_data
eigen_build opencv_contrib  pcl
eigen_install   opendetection
```

All good so far, now let's try to configure opendetection and generate a solution into opendetection_build, and find pendetection's dependencies *from within the ~/src folder*, that is for the first two dependencies, I hope to find opencv and eigen in the opencv-build and eigen-build folders.

OpenCV immediately fails, as expected, saying:

```
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any of the following names:

OpenCVConfig.cmake
opencv-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "OpenCV" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

That's good, because I want to explicitly tell CMake to look for dependent packages under my ~/src folder. Question: Is the use of CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/users/foo/src the recommended way to accomplish what I want - looking for all sub-packages under a specific path?

Following this, CMake finds OpenCV (good), and sets OpenCV_DIR = /Users/foo/src/opencv-build.

Question: Given that I have made an "install" to opencv-install (using CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX and building the Install Target Of OpenCV, shouldn't it find OpenCV in the opencv-install folder not opencv-build?

Moving on to eigen, I have configured and built eigen, and installed it to ~/src/eigen-install, which since it is a subfolder of CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH (~/src) I might expect to be found. But it doesn't seem to be. Can somebody explain to me what I'm not understanding? Particularly given that Eigen in a template library, and that there are at least three folders (eigen, eigen_build and eigen_install)  under CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH which I would have thought CMake would find something in, I assume I must be doing something wrong here. I KNOW from past experience, I can set EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR by hand in CMakeGUI by hand, and continue hacking forth, but that just seems wrong.

I'm more than willing to write up a web page explaining this for future people as dumb as me if one does not already exist, although I can't understand how use of CMake for basic project configuration and generation is apparently so obvious to everyone but so opaque for me. I have actually been using CMake for some years, usually by just manually setting Boost_INCLUDE_Dir, Foo_INCLUDE_PATH etc manually, but clearly this is not the right solution. Generally, after spending a couple of days fighting through the various packages to generate a solution by manually setting INCLUDE PATHS, LIBRARY PATHS and other options, I just deal with the solution and don't touch CMake again. But I would love to understand what I'm missing about find_package for my (surely not uncommon) use case of wanting to control my project dependencies rather than just using sudo port install * and installing random versions of projects to my global system folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As error message says, `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` should be set to *installation prefix* of the package. E.g., if the package has been built using CMake, this is `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` variable's value, if the package has been build using Autotools, this is value of `--prefix` option used for configure it, and so on.

CMake doesn't search every directory under CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH. That is why specifying it as `/users/foo/src` is useless if you have the package installed at `/users/foo/src/eigen-install`.

Instead, you may install *all* 3d-party packages into `/users/foo/src/install`, and use that path as *CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH* in your main project.

Comment: This is the clearest comment I've heard yet, and fully explains the behaviour. But to clarify, is there *no* way in CMake to achieve what I want, with cleanly separated installations? Granted, I can clearly now make my own "install" sub-folder, but I don't understand why I would want to do that and install everything to "install". A folder with VTK, opencv, pcl, etc all dumped into it is a fairly mostrous folder, and there's then no way to clean-rebuild a sub-package if I, for example, choose to update it.

Comment: `is there no way in CMake to achieve what I want, with cleanly separated installations?` - It is possible, but you need to explicitely specify all installation prefixes in that case. E.g., you may collect all of them into `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` (this variable may actually be a *list*). `there's then no way to clean-rebuild a sub-package if I, for example, choose to update it.` - Usually, `make uninstall` cleanly removes package's files from install directory and does not touch other packages in the same dir. So having single install prefix doesn't prevent rebuilding separate packages.

Comment: Thanks. In generally I trust people to write uninstall scripts less than I trust blowing away the folder they wrote to, but your suggestions give me everything I need to work. 

I am a little confused about why OpenCV *was* found (albeit in an arbitrary sub-folder.) Does this imply that OpenCV has overridden the behaviour of find_package, and is such an override common?